# How to list all leaf files under a directory in reverse time order?

Tags: directory

Given a directory, how can we list all its leaf files in time reverse order? `ls -Rltr` ist the content of a subdirectory in time reverse order, but groups files by subdirectory, which break the requirement of listing all the leaf files (regardless of their parent directories) in time reverse order. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' **/*(D^om/:t)
```

Those are glob qualifiers, a feature unique to `zsh` at this time.

- `D`: include dot-files
- `^`: reverse the following qualifiers
- `om`: order on modification time (reversed with `^`)
- `/`: exclude (with `^`) files of type *directory*.
- `:t`: a modifier that gets the *tail* of the file (the basename).

(if you want the full path as opposed to just the basename, just remove `:t`).

With `bash` or any shell, provided `zsh` is available:

```
zsh -c 'printf "%s\n" **/*(D^om/:t)'
```

or on a GNU system:

```
find . ! -type d -printf '%T@\t%f\0' | sort -zn |
  tr '\n\0' '\0\n' | cut -f2- | tr '\0' '\n'
```

(if you want the full path as opposed to just the basename, just replace `%f` with `%P` or `%p` (same as `./%P` here)).

Comment: thanks. what does `**/*(DOm:t)` mean?  Is this possible in bash?

Comment: @Tim, see edit.

Comment: thanks. is there some convenient way to list the (possibly relative wrt the starting directory, but may be absolute) pathname of each file in the ordered list? (pathname, because it saves for further finding a file from a given basename, and removes ambiguity for files with same basename; relative pathname, because absolute pathname may be long)

Comment: @Tim, I thought that's what you were asking for which is why I added explicit code to remove the dirname (:t, and %f instead of %p). Removed now. See edit.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for confusion. your original reply is also what I like to know.  I like to know both. either is useful sometimes